# Use string as part of [JSON valueForKeyPath] selector?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm parsing JSON which looks like:

```
{"data":{"items":{"daily":{"2013-07-31":16}}}}
```

I've built a date string. e.g:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"Y-MM-d"];

NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:now];
```

How do I use **dateString** as part of the valueForKeyPath selector?

```
[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.daily"]?
```

Comment: Why do you want a single keypath? `[[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.daily"] objectForKey:dateString]` seems like the easiest way to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your keyPath string using `+stringWithFormat:` method and then use it. You will have something like (assuming JSON is an object that you already parsed from json string):

```
NSString *keyPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data.items.daily.%@", dateString];
id valueYouLookFor = [JSON valueForKeyPath: keyPath]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a string format:

```
[JSON valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data.items.daily.%@", dateString]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this `stringWithFormat:` method would be helpful:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data.items.daily.%@", dateString];
```

Comment: `stringWithFormat` with just a single string specifier (`@"%@"`) is absolutely useless and costs unneeded parsing. Imagine I said to you "Tell me what you'd say if I said you to say Hi" vs. "Say hi". Just use `dateString` directly in this case.

Comment: @Cyrille You are correct. I was just suggesting the 'stringWithFormat:' method. However, I'll edit my answer for clarification.